# Want to Read a big file and SendKeys it at once

Tags: c#, selenium

I have an HTML that I need to read the content and them send it to a textbox using selenium.

I can read the archive and send it, but some of my HTML´s are so big and takes a long time to SendKeys character to character.

I want a way to paste all my HTML content at the TextBox quickly, at once.

I´ve thinking about using SendKeys.Send("^{v}")
But I don´t know hot to copy fullHtml

Is there a way to do something like a CTRL A and CTRL C in the HTML?

```
string fullHtml = File.ReadAllText(path+file);

//Removing TAB from the HTML, because TAB leaving the textbox 
char tab = '\u0009';
fullHtml = fullHtml.Replace(tab.ToString(), "");

driver.FindElement(By.Id("TxtConteudo")).SendKeys(fullHtml);
```

Comment: `System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(fullHtml);`

Comment: @RufusL Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve, it was important to Clear Clipboard em define STAThread.

```
string fullHtml = File.ReadAllText(path+file);

//Retirando TAB do arquivo HTML, pois o mesmo não permite o envio de várias linhas de arquivo.
char tab = '\u0009';
fullHtml = fullHtml.Replace(tab.ToString(), "");

Thread STAThread = new Thread(
delegate ()
{
    Clipboard.Clear();
    System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(fullHtml);
});
STAThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
STAThread.Start();
STAThread.Join();

driver.FindElement(By.Id("TxtConteudo")).Click();
SendKeys.SendWait(@"^{V}");
```